# ERROR: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cronjobs

Buenas tardes estoy programando unos email automáticos para recordar la fecha de una cita al cliente, para ello estoy utilizando cronjobs y mail de Laravel.

La automatización de que comprueba cada minuto la tengo correcta, pero a la hora de hacer la consulta que necesito no hace nada, y los logs no me quedan muy claros, paso a detallar lo que intento hacer y conseguir.

**Primero obtengo la fecha actual y le sumo un día, por que me interesa saber que citas hay mañana**

```
$fecha_actual = date("Y-m-d");
$fechaSiguiente = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($fecha_actual."+ 1 days"));
```

**Luego busco en mi tabla comparando si hay alguna cita mañana**

```
$citasdema = \DB::table('contactos')->where('cita', $fechaSiguiente)->get();
```

**Luego las itero y mando mail a cada una**

```
foreach($citasdema as $cita ){
  $elEmail = $cita->email;

  Mail::send('emails.pruebas', ['datos'=>$cita], function($message) use ($elEmail)
    {
     $message->to($elEmail)
         ->subject('Información - Cita');
     });
    }
```

**Y por último en mi archivo `emails.pruebas`**

```
Hola tienes una cita mañana {{ $datos['nombre'] }}
```

Pero no recibo nada y abriendo el archivo logs recibo esto:

```
[2021-07-24 13:06:01] local.ERROR: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array (View: /var/www/massidental/resources/views/emails/pruebas.blade.php) {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Cannot use object of type stdClass as array (View: /var/www/massidental/resources/views/emails/pruebas.blade.php) at /var/www/massidental/storage/framework/views/a6c7c8eeb99b01039f8b1740ad5bebad155c9c0f.php:10, Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Cannot use object of type stdClass as array at /var/www/storage/framework/views/a6c7c8eeb99b01039f8b1740ad5bebad155c9c0f.php:10)
[stacktrace]
```

**Edición**
Viendo lo bien, si lo que llevo al mail tengo que iterarlo, pero no creo que este bien, que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Tenias razón @BetaM tenia que acceder así `$variable->propiedad` Muchas gracias por tu comentario como siempre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma de solucionar mi problema es como comenta el compañero BetaM. Al no ser un array tengo que acceder a la variable de este modo:

```
$variable->propiedad
```